# Java preprocessor - insert code into every function

Tags: java, preprocessor, aspectj

I am looking for a utility that will allow me to take as input a huge number of .java files (that I am not allowed to modify) and output the same files modified with these changes:

1. Add an import statement to the top of the file
2. In every function matching a certain regex (i.e. `* com.foo.*.draw*(*)`)...

   1. Insert `Func.begin([function name])` at the start of the function, where [function name] is the fully qualified function name (`void com.foo.circle.drawLine(int,int)`)
   2. Insert `Func.end([function name])` at the bottom of the function

However, I do not want to use AspectJ for this task because it works with .class files and would potentially slow down things.

Any ideas?

Comment: So let me sum it up, you want to do AOP without doing AOP?

Comment: It doesn't work with .class files. Look into load-time weaving.

Comment: How does adding a preprocessor not modify your build process?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: are you sure? "The AspectJ weaver takes class files as input and produces class files as output." corsiKa: You're right I reworded that part of my question

Comment: That is only one way that AspectJ can work. You didn't look into load-time weaving, did you?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I had researched it. However, if I understand correctly, it modifies .class files as they are loaded, which is a double-hit in performance (one for run-time weaving and two for the overhead of the aspects). Anyways, what I am looking for is something lighter weight than AspectJ

Comment: Did you measure the performance hit? I doubt it is even measurable except when executing an empty method in a tight loop. If looking for something lightweight, a nonstandard Java preprocessor is definitely NOT the way.

Comment: AspectJ will not slow down your code any more than your generated code will. It is a highly optimised framework and probably a bit smarter than your intended self-made code generation framework.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will start out with AspectJ and, if perform does become an issue, I will switch to Gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably use Gradle.  You wouldn't need to make any of the projects gradle projects, but could just define a user-defined task to do the work.  For substitutions into existing files (leaving those files in place), I found the ant task support to be a bit easier to use than the gradle "Copy" task.  If you need to leave the original files unchanged you should use that!

You can use replace to insert the "import":

```
task addImportStatement << {
    ant.replace(dir: 'yourSrcDirHere', token: 'existing value', value:'<![CDATA[existing value
    new import statement here]]>')
}

task regExpressionSub << {
    ant.replaceRegExp(...)
}
regExpressionSub.dependsOn addImportStatement
```

The details for the ant tasks are [available in the online ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I think I will start out with AspectJ and, if perform does become an issue, I will switch to Gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Try my Java Comment preprocessor, it has special features to form both prefix and postfix sections (I used it for import sections)
http://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/